# Save multiple character against single player ID in GameSpark

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, unity-game-engine

I am working on MMO game. I have to save multiple character and its info against single ID because in my game a player can save multiple heroes (can play from single one). I created an event, but when user told db to create character it simply update last information.

```
 var CharacterDataList = Spark.runtimeCollection("CharacterData");
 var playerID = Spark.getPlayer().getPlayerId();
 var characterSelected = Spark.getData().CS;
 var weaponLevel = Spark.getData().WL;
 var cname = Spark.getData().NAME;
 var wins = Spark.getData().WINS;
 var loss = Spark.getData().LOSS;
 var gold = Spark.getData().GOLD;
 var currentCharacter = {
     "playerID": playerID,
     "characterSelected": characterSelected,
     "weaponLevel": weaponLevel,
     "name": cname,
     "wins": wins,
     "loss": loss,
     "gold": gold
 }; // we construct a new player from the data we are about to input into the player data
 CharacterDataList.update({
     "playerID": playerID
 }, //Looks for a doc with the id of the current player
 {
     "$set": currentCharacter
 }, // Uses the $set mongo modifier to set old player data to the current player data
 true, // Create the document if it does not exist (upsert)
 false // This query will only affect a single object (multi)
 );
```

Above code will run on cloud. How can I save new character against an id. I found a command of Insert but I don't know how to use it in my case to Add information. The Unity Code is below.

```
    public void CreateCharacterData(){
    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.LogEventRequest ()
        .SetEventKey ("SAVE_CHARACTER_INFO")
        .SetEventAttribute ("CS", "Humans")
        .SetEventAttribute ("WL", 1)
        .SetEventAttribute ("NAME", "ghfsdgfsj")
        .SetEventAttribute ("WINS", 0)
        .SetEventAttribute ("LOSS", 0)
        .SetEventAttribute ("GOLD",100)
        .Send((GameSparks.Api.Responses.LogEventResponse obj) => {
            if(!obj.HasErrors){
                print("Added Character");
            }else{
                print("Error");
            }
        });
}
```

I found a link but I am still confused [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274998/how-to-post-a-list-of-data-into-gamespark-runtime-collection-unity-c-sharp).

Comment: Can you show your db structure?

Comment: @Shrabanee sorry didn't get your point

Comment: I will suggest to use an array of objects for selected characters. Every time user is selecting a character, you can just push that information into the array of selected characters.

Comment: I was asking you to show us your data base structure (you can put a sample structure in the question you have asked by editing it), so that it will be easier to understand your issue and help you out.

Comment: @Shrabanee aha. but how to save it in gamespark

Comment: @Shrabanee I mean what will be the datatype on gamespark. it only support Number, String and JSON

Comment: Sorry pal! I have no idea about gamespark. :( I can help you out with mongodb only.

Comment: okay No problem. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This post was answered by us here: https://support.gamesparks.net/discussions/topics/1000082602

If you need any further assistance please do not hesitate to get back in touch.

If anyone else has similar issues you can contact our support team directly via https://support.gamesparks.net - We're always happy to offer our assistance!

Clare